# Generate A Java Class From A Java Application

Tags: java, class, runtime

I am trying to create a data validation program that checks if a specific data type is valid by running each "type" (eg. name, age, gender) through its own validation method (each method is unique to its data type), the only problem is I want the application to be flexible to different data types and different amounts of data types.

Is there a way I can actually generate an entirely new Java application with methods for each type from the running Java application (for example "writing" a new class) during runtime once I have all the types?

Example Code:

```
public class JavaGen(){
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int dataLength = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Amount Of Data Types:"));
        String[] dataTypeList = new String[dataLength];

        //Fill up dataTypeList with user input
        writeJavaFile(dataTypeList);
    }

    public void writeJavaFile(String[] dataTypes){
        //Create the new class and its methods here using the array of dataTypes
    }
}
```

Which, for example, will then create a class of methods similar to this:

```
public class ActualClass(){
    public String validate'What The dataTypes[x] was'(String infoToValidate){
        if(etc etc){
            return "etc etc";
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you don't know these custom types at compile-time? Where do they come from? And what would the generated classes be used for?

Comment: @MickMnemonic The custom types would be entered by the application's user as it starts up so no I don't have them at compile-time. The generated class would be a method class with all the validation methods that need to be created (as each type will need its own specific method)

Comment: I'm still not seeing the full picture. If the user can input _any_ type definition, how could the validation logic be auto-generated? A common approach to defining custom data types is to express them in e.g. an XML schema and then generate Java binding objects through [JAXB](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding). Could you do something similar?

Comment: *Face-table* I hadn't thought of that...it seems I'm clearly over-complicating this...I think maybe I'll just stick to hard coding in a range of possible types for the user to choose, but thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0):

You can create, compile and instantiate a java class in runtime.

See this:
http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/create-a-java-source-dynamically-compile-and.html

**Some libraries:** 
cglib
Codemodel

Or you could use Nashorn. (javascript interpreter) I can imagine a use case where user defines complex validation in javascript and then this would be a good approach.

Although in your case I would not recommend any of the above and just write it in the code. Data types validation sounds like something you want to have hard-coded.

Comment: So maybe just rather enter in a whole range of data types and simply only allow data types from within that range, then use the appropriate methods?

Comment: Yes, that would be probably the best approach. If you don't need user to define his own data type.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I'll just be going with that then, sorry for the time wasting :/

Answer (score 0):

**I can tell you right off that bat you are approaching a simple problem with an incredibly complex solution...**

I would *guess* you are looking for the `instanceof` keyword, or perhaps an abstract validation class.

If you could be more specific with your intended functionality we could help you come up with a reasonable design pattern.

**Directly to your question:** 
Yes, you can generate and load classes in Java on the fly.  It involves invoking the `defineClass(String, byte[], int, int)` method in the reflection package.  As input to this function you have to provide a byte array of the class you are instantiating.  *This doesn't sound like the appropriate approach to this problem.*

Comment: Basically the intended functionality is:
1: The user chooses a series of data types they want and then create a number of "objects", so each object has all of those types, and then of course inputs the data for each "object".
2: All the data for each object's types are then validated by sending that data to a method which returns a string of errors.
3: If there are any errors with the data it is then displayed alongside the original data so the user can fix the errors.

Comment: Based on your comments there is nothing required here than a tuple: the data as a string, and the expected type.  Store it all in an array list of container objects.